# Why do non-escaped, double-quoted paths work for a test, but not for an alias?

Tags: scripting, bash

I'm trying to set an alias to a program only when there is an existing executable file at a certain path. I've been using double quotation marks for paths and aliases in all my scripts thus far, but have run across a problem using them with paths that include spaces.

For example, I've set a variable thusly: `PATH_TO_SUBL="/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"`. Testing it (`[[ -x $PATH_TO_SUBL ]]`) works, but using it in an alias doesn't (`alias subl=$PATH_TO_SUBL` results in bash returning */Applications/Sublime: No such file or directory*).

When I set it with single quotes and escaped spaces (`PATH_TO_SUBL='/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'`) both the test and alias work. Why is that?

Comment: For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions. -- `bash` man page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
alias subl="$PATH_TO_SUBL"
```

otherwise your your alias command will be parsed as:

```
alias suble=/some/thing else/here
```

which doesn't make a proper alias definition.

(It works without quotes in the `[[ ... ]]` conditional since those are processed by the shell directly with rules for it to work. It wouldn't work if you actually used `test` with a `[ ... ]` conditional.)

Comment: +1 The technical explanation is that word-splitting, performed elsewhere by the shell, is not performed inside the `[[...]]` compound command.

Comment: ``PATH_TO_SUBL="/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"`` (double quotes, escaped spaces) fails the ``[[ -x $PATH_TO_SUBL ]]`` and ``[[ -x "$PATH_TO_SUBL" ]]`` but ``alias subl="$PATH_TO_SUBL"`` will work. Setting ``PATH_TO_SUBL`` with double quotes but _without escaping spaces_ changes this: ``[[…]]`` pass, but the ``subl`` alias results in "/Applications/Sublime: No such file or directory." So, if I care to be consistent in how I use strings, should I stick with single quotes and escaped spaces?

Comment: Don't escape spaces within quotes (single or double). And don't use aliases. Put the things you need to run in your path, use symlinks to get them in your path, or use functions - all those will work.

Comment: @lucasrizoli An alias definition goes through two levels of quote/escape application and removal, one when you use the `alias` command to define the alias, and another when you actually use the alias. This makes their syntax weird and inconsistent with everything else, and is one of the reasons it's better to use functions instead.